# HTML table in Email

Tags: php, html, html-table, html-email

I have made the following email template, 
but instead of shown data in table format; it shows the complete Html codes in the email body. Please help me fix this.

```
 <table style="font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px; background: #fff; margin: 45px; width: 480px; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left;" summary="Website Uptime Statistics">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; color: #039; padding: 10px 8px; border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;" scope="col">#S.No.</th>
        <th style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; color: #039; padding: 10px 8px; border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;" scope="col">Website</th>
        <th style="font-size: 14px; font-weight: normal; color: #039; padding: 10px 8px; border-bottom: 2px solid #6678b1;" scope="col">Status</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>


    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #669; padding: 6px 8px;">1</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #669; padding: 6px 8px;">http://google.com</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #669; padding: 6px 8px;">Up</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #009; padding: 6px 8px;">2</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #009; padding: 6px 8px;">http://google.com</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #009; padding: 6px 8px;">Down</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #669; padding: 6px 8px;">$300</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #669; padding: 6px 8px;">$300</td>
        <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; color: #669; padding: 6px 8px;">$300</td>
    </tr>




</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: @hakiko nope! Should enclose this table in a div?

Comment: I was do it before then i re-wrote it with divs. you can try enclose this code block with divs, only try :)

Comment: are you trying to send this using C# asp.net

Comment: @hakiko tried. didn't work

Comment: @Raghurocks working in PHP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you set the content-type of the email so the receiving email application knows it contains HTML and can therefore present it properly?

`Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Answer (score -3):

```
$html = '';
$html .= ' <table style="font-family: Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande, Sans-Serif; font-size: 12px; background: #fff; margin: 45px; width: 480px; border-collapse: collapse; text-align: left;" summary="Website Uptime Statistics"><thead>';
.....
echo $html;
```

try this

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve with this?